# How to use a callable function in Pandas str.replace?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, whose for a particular column the values will be replaced by the function, so lets say the table is as follows:

```
Att1    Att2     Att3 .....
142+75
90+25
78+10
```

Now, I am using a function to replace the values as follows:

```
Att1          Att2     Att3
142+75_142+76
90+25_90+26
78+10_78+11
```

I have tried the following code:

```
df['Att1'] = df['Att1'].str.replace(df['Att1'],func(df['Att1']))
```

The function is working fine, how do I pass this value as a callable in the str.replace() so that the Att1 value is passed into the function and the modified value returns back?

Comment: Add the code you have tried.

Comment: I think you are simply looking for `apply` instead of `str.replace`.

Comment: @HenryYik you were right. Finally did this with `apply`.

Answer (score 0):

you can actually callable in replace function like below. The lambda function will give you group match from regex. you can replace print with your function

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([['142+75'], ['90+25'], ['78+10']], columns=['Att1'])

df.Att1.str.replace("(\d+)\+(\d+)", lambda x: print(x[1], x[2]))

## pass whole match
df.Att1.str.replace("(\d+)\+(\d+)", lambda x: print(x[0]))
```

Comment: I dont want to pass a number, i want to pass the whole value into the function.

Comment: x[0] will give whole value

Comment: But where are you passing? I have a function which is some 4 to 5 lines of code. Can I pass to that?

Comment: ya you can replace print with your function name

Comment: This is not working. I am using it like this: df['Att1'] = df['Att1'].str.replace(r'(^\n)+', lambda x : func(x[0]), regex = True)